# How can I read a bgz file in an R program, or convert it to something that R can read?

Tags: r, readr

I need to read a GWAS file called nnnnn.gwas.imputed_v3.both_sexes.tsv.bgz
How can I read this in R, or convert it to something that R can read?

Tried

```
aa_100022 <- read_tsv(100022.gwas.imputed_v3.both_sexes.tsv.bgz)
```

and  got this message:

> Error: unexpected symbol in "aa_100022 <-
> read_tsv(100022.gwas.imputed_v3.both_sexes.tsv.bgz"

The doc for read_delim says Files ending in .gz, .bz2, .xz, or .zip will be automatically uncompressed. No mention of .bgz
Also not working on this file: read.tsv, read_csv, read.csv - Same message

So, I am back to the question of how do I decompress .bgz? Can this be done in R, or does the file need preprocessing before I get to R? Is this a SuperUser question?

Comment: Off-topic: [*"recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource "*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you can provide a sample of what the file looks like and some code you've tried to parse it, you'll be okay, but as is this question will likely be closed.

Comment: Re: @r2evans suggestion to add code that you've tried, have you tried `read.delim("nnnnn.gwas.imputed_v3.both_sexes.tsv.bgz")` (`read.delim()`  can be used for tab-separated files (implied by `.tsv`))? I've never tried it specifically with a `bgz` file, but from `help("read.delim")`, its input "can be a compressed file (see file)."

Comment: Apologies, I'm familiar with `.tar.gz`, `.tgz`, `.tar.bz2`, and `.tbz2`, but was not aware of `bgzip` (how does it compare to `gzip` and `bzip2`?) and ergo its `.bgz` ending. So showing sample data from a compressed file ain't gonna work :-). That doesn't really solve the problem of how to ask the question on SO, sorry.

Comment: Since `.bgz` files [can be decompressed with `gunzip`](http://www.htslib.org/doc/bgzip.html), R should support it natively. I just `gzip`ed a local CSV, renamed to `file.csv.bgz`, and this worked: `read.csv("file.csv.bgz")`. So have you tried (as @duckmayr suggested) just reading it via your normal TSV-reading function?

Answer (score 2):

You can use gunzip function from R.utils package.

e.g.

```
aa_100022 <- gunzip(“original file name.tsv.bgz”, “destinate file name.tsv”)

aa_100022 <- read_tsv(“destinate file name.tsv”)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'connections' from base R to read various types of compressed files into R directly, without needing to decompress it.

```
bgz <- gzfile('file.csv.bgz','rt')  
myData <- read.csv(bgz)
```